# Which JAR to use for JSTL?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I want to use JSTL, however, there are 4 different JAR files on [this Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl).

i.e.: `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api`, `jstl-api`, `jstl`, and `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.wso2`

So, my questions are:

1. What are the differences between those JARs?
2. Which one to include among those on our project?

Answer (score 0):

For JSTL include [jstl-1.2](http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) in WEB-INF lib folder and classpath, or if you are using maven you can use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
 </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try the follwing

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>taglibs</groupId>
<artifactId>standard</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```